# Cannot push to a repo in mac OS from my account?

Tags: git, macos

I have a public repository made from my personal git hub account. I have 2 git hub accounts one for my company and one my personal account. When I am trying to push to my repository. It gives following error

```
Permission to akashpandey2193/fitness-website.git denied to akashpandey21.
```

First I thought it is because of my username and user email not set for the repo so I did set it using

```
git config --local user.name "Akash"
git config --local user.email "akashpandey2193@gmail.com"
```

same error came. It shows the username of my company account even though the user name set is my in git config file for my repository. I have worked with multiple accounts on ubuntu never experienced such a issue. Is this a mac thing?

Comment: why was my question down voted atleast tell the reason

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem: You don't have write access to this repository.

Comment: I have the access to it as it is my own repository to begin with. I have 2 git hub accounts which I access from my own pc that is creating a issue.